# Pushing to a string instead of an array fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, for-loop

I'm trying to change the input string. However, when I try to change the `resultArray` to a string, it won't work. When I call `typeof` on the `resultArray`, it returns object.

```js
let input = 'Coding is so great.';
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
let resultArray = [];

function getVowels(input) {

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {
      if (vowels[j] === input[i]) {
        resultArray.push(vowels[j]);
      }
    }
    if (input[i] == 'e') {
      resultArray.push(input[i]);
    }
    if (input[i] == 'u') {
      resultArray.push(input[i]);
    }
  }
  resultArray.join('');
  console.log(resultArray);
}
getVowels(input);
```

Comment: Because `.push()` is not something you can do to a string. Try `resultArray += input[i]` to add to a string, instead of pushing.

Comment: The `typeof` an array in JavaScript is `object`. If you want to see if it's an array, use `Array.isArray`. JavaScript has other ways to do deal with types besides the `typeof` operator, its `typeof` is limited because it was designed in the 1990s and  JavaScript has to be backward compatible.

Comment: Keegan, you should resolve all ambiguities by showing exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The array `.join` method does not mutate the array in any way. It returns a string of the joined elements. In your snippet, you're logging the original `resultArray` after a call to `join`, when you should be logging the result of the `join` call itself:

```js
let input = 'Coding is so great.';
const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
let resultArray = [];

function getVowels(input) {

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++) {
      if (vowels[j] === input[i]) {
        resultArray.push(vowels[j]);
      }
    }
    if (input[i] == 'e') {
      resultArray.push(input[i]);
    }
    if (input[i] == 'u') {
      resultArray.push(input[i]);
    }
  }
  
  console.log(resultArray.join('')); // <-- this is the value you want, not `resultArray`
  
  // console.log(resultArray);
}

getVowels(input);
```

If you really want to change the `resultArray` to a string, you have to re-assign it:

```
resultArray = resultArray.join('')
```

But I would not recommend doing so. Generally, you should avoid side-effects like that within your functions. It would be better to define `resultArray` within `getVowels` and return the resulting string instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```js
let vowels = "Coding is great".split('').filter(c => /[aeiou]/.test(c));

console.log(vowels.join(''));
```

Additionally, you can tag it:

```js
function vowels(tmpl, ...parts) {
    return tmpl.reduce((s, t, i, arr) => s += t + (i<arr.length-1 ? parts[i] : ''))
               .split('')
               .filter(c => /[aeiou]/.test(c)).join('');
}

console.log(vowels `Coding is great!`);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not actually returning anything from your function.  I think this means your return value is `undefined` in JS.  Use the `return` keyword instead of falling of the end of your function.

Comment: No where in there is he checking the output from the function. Although this would be ideal to return the results from the function, this is not where his problem lies.